# How do you say “buy” in the sense of “believe”?

Tags: expressions, traduction, registre-familier

Is there a French equivalent for saying something like “I don’t buy it!” meaning “I don’t believe that at all!”?

Answer (score 11):

Here are various ways that might express "**[I don't buy it](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/449278/origin-of-i-don-t-buy-it)**" in French:

Formal:

> — Je n'en crois pas un mot.
>
> — Je n'y crois pas une seconde.

Spoken French:

> — Je marche<sup>1</sup> pas.
>
> — À d'autres<sup>2</sup>.
>
> — Je la gobe<sup>3</sup> pas, ton histoire. (Italians say: *non me la sono bevuta*: "I didn't drink it")
>
> — On ne me la fait pas<sup>4</sup>.

In addition, cl-r suggested these sentences that keep the financial side of the English idiom:

> — Je ne parierai pas un kopeck là-dessus.
>
> — C’est de la roupie de sansonnet ce truc.
>
> — Ça ne vaut pas une thune ton histoire.

<sub>1 [TLFi:](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/marcher) **C. - 2. b)** Croire naïvement ce que l'on vous raconte. *Marcher à fond; marcher à tous les coups. Vous aussi, Alvare, vous avez marché !* (Lemercier, *Pinto*, 10, 5, 13, p.158).</sub>

<sub>2 [Wiktionnaire:](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_d%E2%80%99autres) **1.** (*Familier*) (*Par ellipse*) Se dit ironiquement pour signifier que l’on n’est pas dupe de ce qu’on nous raconte.</sub>

<sub>3 [TLFI:](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gober) **C. - 1.** Croire sans discernement tout ce qui se dit. *La petite Besse (...) était d'une simplicité incroyable, elle aurait gobé n'importe quoi* (Genevoix, *Mains vides*, 1928, p. 136)</sub>

<sub>4 [Wiktionnaire:](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/on_ne_me_la_fait_pas) **1.** Je ne suis pas aussi crédule que vous semblez le croire.</sub>

Comment: Pour rester dans le monde de l’argent : — Je ne parierai pas un kopeck là-dessus — C’est de la roupie de sansonnet ce truc — Ça ne vaut pas une thune ton histoire

Comment: « À d'autres » est plutôt abusivement considéré comme familier ; je ne perçois pas cette nuance et elle n'est pas non plus mentionnée dans le TLFi ; c'est une locution qui appartient au registre courant. « Je ne marche pas. » ne correspond pas : il n'est question que de façons de procéder sur lesquelles on n'est pas d'accord.

Comment: @LPH Ni *to buy*, ni *marcher* n'impliquent la présence d'accord sur un processus. *Je lui ai fait croire que j'étais agent secret et il a marché".

Comment: @jlliagre D'abord je n'insinue pas que « to buy » implique un processus, cela concerne « marcher » seulement et « marcher » implique certainement un arrangement sous entendu, un processus quelconque; secondement,puisqu'on vient de dire que l'on **a fait croire à la personne** qu'on est un agent secret, quel est le besoin de répéter qu'elle l'a cru, qu'elle l'a avaler, qu'elle a marché; on veut dire plutôt que sur cette base de mensonge elle a adopté le comportement voulu.

Comment: @jlliagre  Ex. pour marcher; — Toi tu vas au faire la vaisselle et je vais me reposer. — Ah ! Non, je ne marche pas, passe à la vaisselle. Je reconnais cependant que « marcher » peut être pris dans certains cas comme ayant le sens de « avaler » mais pas dans ce cas précis d'un emploi négatif en réponse à des mensonges (Je ne marche pas.); Ex. — Tu lui racontes ces histoires, et il marche ? — Eh  Oui ! Il marche.

Comment: @jlliagre  (TLFi)  Donner son entière adhésion à (quelqu'un ou quelque chose). Alors, vous marchez? Je marche. 
Pop. Marcher dans la combine. Moi, j'marche pas dans la combine.  b) Croire naïvement ce que l'on vous raconte. Marcher à fond; marcher à tous les coups.

Comment: « Roupie de sansonnet » n'a rien à faire là-dedans, ça signifie « chose sans importance » : (TLFi) Expr., pop., fam. De la roupie de singe (vieilli), de sansonnet. Une chose insignifiante. [Souvent en empl. nég. pour qualifier une chose remarquable] On s'assit autour de la table, et le zingueur voulut verser le café lui-même. Il sentait joliment fort, ce n'était pas de la roupie de sansonnet (ZOLA, Assommoir, 1877, p. 470).

Comment: Même chose pour « Ça vaut pas une thune. » Cela signifie seulement « C'est sans valeur. » ; ça n'a rien à voir avec une traduction de « to buy ».

Comment: @LPH — DeepL donne ***Je n'y crois pas.***, mettriez-vous même *une thune, un kopeck, une roupie* après avoir proclamé "I don't buy it" ?

Comment: @cl-r Je fonde mon assertion sur ma connaissance personnelle de l'expression, tout d'abord, et le TLFi confirme ce que je crois : en aucun cas il ne s'agit de croire ou ne pas croire mais seulement de prononcer un jugement sur l'importance de quelque chose ; même chose pour « thune », une question de valeur, d'importance, pas de vérité. « je ne parierais pas » est une toute autre chose que « C'est de » et  « sansonnet » n'a plus rien à faire là-dedans …

Comment: @LPH *Et il a marché* peut très bien signifier *et il y a cru*. C'est d'ailleurs l'une des définitions du TLFi que j'ai indiquée, et que tu reprends dans l'un de tes commentaires: *croire naïvement ce qu'on vous raconte*. Quant aux propositions de cl-r, elles s'éloignent un peu des traductions s'attachant à préserver la signification de l'expression anglaise figurée pour y ajouter une touche évoquant l'esprit de cette expression. Dans *I don't buy it*, même au sens figuré, on ne peut pas contester que la notion d'achat, de prix, de valeur ou ici d'absence de valeur soit encore présente.

Comment: Lisez de nouveau la question : “I don’t buy it!” **meaning** “**I don’t believe that at all**!”; il n'y a pas de notion de valeur, vraiment, qu'une question de vérité. le dictionnaire d'anglais confirme cela : (informal) to believe that something is true, especially something that is not very likely.

Comment: @LPH https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/449278/origin-of-i-don-t-buy-it

Comment: Voir aussi [Larousse en ligne](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/buy/567945?q=buy+it).

Answer (score 3):

In a colloquial manner of speaking you can use the verb "avaler", but I believe personally it is somewhat less acceptable than the alledged "familiar" register label that comes with it would have us believe. Nevertheless it will do for "buy" as this sense of the word ranges from slang to informal in English. There is a derogatory connotation in this word, from my point of view, and it is a fleeting notion that the dictionaries do not tell of.

- Cette histoire, il n'a pas pu l'avaler et il ne l'avalera jamais.
- Je n'avale pas ça, vous me racontez des histoires pour les gogos.
- Il avale tout ce qu'on lui dit, un enfant le bernerait.

Here is an essential difference in the use of this verb; whereas in English you say quite naturally "Yes, I can buy that!" or "I'll buy that.", in French you can't say "J'avale ça !" or "Je l'avale"; it seems to me I never heard that and the derogatory aspect I mention could well be the reason (subconscious realisation of the fact by the speaker). The only possibility would be as a reply to a [(very) derogatory question/question asked in puzzlement] such as "(Et) Vous avalez ça ?", when the person answering wants to make quite clear she/he does believe whatever has come into question ("(Oui !) Je l'avale !"). Nevertheless, if the statement is fully qualified positively or negatively qualified there is no problem.

- <s>Je l'avale bien.</s> (je le crois bien.)
- Je l'avale en partie. Je l'avale presque. Je l'avale mal. Il avale ça difficilement.
- Si je l'avale c'est parce que j'ai de bonnes indications qu'il ne ment pas.
- Je l'avale oui et non, quand il me dit qu'il croit je n'en croit rien mais quand il me dit être charitable je vois bien qu'il y a du vrai.

Here are expressions to know as they are used fairly often;

> (TLFi) Emploi factitif. [Avec un obj. second, désignant une pers.] **Faire avaler qqc. à qqn.** Le lui faire croire.

The derogatory notion referred to above is clear in this expression: it is often considered that the story or fact that someone has been made to believe (faire avaler à qqn) is lies or tainted with lie.

> [Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/avaler/6930?q=avaler#6895)
>   Familier. **Avaler une histoire, un récit, etc.**, les croire sans le moindre esprit critique.
>   Familier. **Dur à avaler**, se dit de ce qu'il est difficile de croire ou d'accepter, de supporter.

Here again, the manner of believing (sans le moindre esprit critique), characterises the action as one of low standards, wherefrom the deprecatory sense of the word ; people do not consider very highly someone who "avale" stories, they tend to think of them as fools.

Comment: Personnellement je trouve les formulations avec avaler à la première pers. du présent suspectes et vraiment (vraiment) loufoques je dois dire. Pour être bien franc ça me fait penser à un film porno.

Comment: @Survenant9r7 Honni soit qui mâle y pense !  Je penserais tout aussi bien aux avaleurs de sabres, au cirque. Sérieusement, dans une conversation où le concept est énoncé dans l'attente d'une réplique la reprise se comprend ; de toute façon il n'est pas dur de trouver un contexte qui justifie totalement l'emploi : « — Tu avale ça sans broncher ?— Eh oui ! Que veut-tu …Je l'avale et je le sais … Je suis vieux maintenant, je  peux pas faire le difficile.»

Answer (score 1):

I find antiphrasis with the right intonation would work quite well and be just as colloquial as *I don't buy it* :

Oui, bien sûr!

Ouais, c'est ça!